# How to groupby columns from multiple tables with same names?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to run this query but I am getting bad request error - 400 Column name date is ambiguous at [3:1]. I can't able to understand how to do the grouping when the columns have same name.

```
q2 = """
SELECT
date,
SUM(totals.visits) AS visits,
SUM(totals.pageviews) AS pageviews,
SUM(totals.transactions) AS transactions,
SUM(totals.transactionRevenue)/1000000 AS revenue
FROM
bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20160801,
bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20160802,
bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20160803
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date ASC  
"""
df = read_gbq(q2, project_id=project_id, credentials=credentials)
df
```

What I have to do to make this query work?

Comment: Please alias the tables first. Then add join conditions. so whole sql should look like `SELECT
totals.date,
SUM(totals.visits) AS visits, 
SUM(totals.pageviews) AS pageviews,
SUM(totals.transactions) AS transactions,
SUM(totals.transactionRevenue)/1000000 revenue
FROM
bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20160801 totals,
bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20160802 b,
bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20160803 c
where 
totals.id_col = b.id_col and
totals.id_col = c.id_col
GROUP BY totals.date
ORDER BY totals.date `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below instead

```
SELECT
  date,
  SUM(totals.visits) AS visits,
  SUM(totals.pageviews) AS pageviews,
  SUM(totals.transactions) AS transactions,
  SUM(totals.transactionRevenue)/1000000 AS revenue
FROM (
  SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20160801` UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20160802` UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20160803`
)
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date ASC
```